# Go - MySQL inserts even when if NOT NULL set

Tags: mysql, go

I'm writing simple API in Go using MySQL but my MySQL code inserts data to row even the column is set to `NOT NULL`. Here is my code:

schema.sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS seller (
    seller_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    contact varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    street varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    city varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    nip varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    bank varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    account_number varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (seller_id)
);
```

database/mysql/invoice.go

```
func (r *invoiceRepository) CreateSeller(seller *invoice.Seller) error {
        query := "INSERT INTO seller (name, contact, street, city, nip, bank, account_number) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        stmt, err := r.db.Prepare(query)
        if err != nil {
                log.Errorf("Unable to create seller %s: %v", seller.SellerName, err)
                return err
        }

        res, err := stmt.Exec(&seller.SellerName, &seller.SellerContact, &seller.SellerStreet, &seller.SellerCity, &seller.SellerNIP, &seller.SellerBank, &seller.SellerAccountNumber)
        if err != nil {
                log.Errorf("Error while creating seller: %v", err)
                return err
        }

        newID, err := res.LastInsertId()
        if err != nil {
                log.Errorf("Error while getting inserted id: %v", err)
                return err
        }

        log.Infof("Created seller %s [id=%d]", seller.SellerName, newID)
        return nil
}
```

Now when I'm making a POST request (using httpie) with the only seller_name my code creates row even with null columns. It looks like this:
`http POST localhost:8000/api/seller/create seller_name=testt`

Here is how my row looks in table:

```
+-----------+-------+---------+--------+------+-----+------+----------------+
| seller_id | name  | contact | street | city | nip | bank | account_number |
+-----------+-------+---------+--------+------+-----+------+----------------+
|         1 | testt |         |        |      |     |      |                |
+-----------+-------+---------+--------+------+-----+------+----------------+
```

I don't know where I've made a mistake.

EDIT (added model)

```
type Seller struct {
        SellerID            int64  `json:"seller_id"`
        SellerName          string `json:"seller_name"`
        SellerContact       string `json:"seller_contact"`
        SellerStreet        string `json:"seller_street"`
        SellerCity          string `json:"seller_city"`
        SellerNIP           string `json:"seller_nip"`
        SellerBank          string `json:"seller_bank"`
        SellerAccountNumber string `json:"seller_account_number"`
}
```

Comment: *"I don't know where I've made a mistake."* Execute `SELECT @@sql_mode;` ? and paste it here..

Comment: As iám pretty sure your MySQL server seams to be running without SQL mode `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` see [without](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tQW1j2p5nwJjjg2nr9G1mL/2) and [with](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tQW1j2p5nwJjjg2nr9G1mL/1)

Comment: You were expecting it to return an error? An error at the DB layer should be a worst-case scenario; something before that should be sanitizing and validating user inputs. I.e., if you don't want nulls/empties inserted into the DB, they should never make it to your `CreateSeller` function.

Comment: A couple of things: What does `seller` actually look like, are the fields populated (remember: empty strings are *not* nil/NULL values)? More over: you create a prepared statement, but that resource is never closed, after the error check on `r.db.Prepare()`, add a `defer stmt.Close()`, please.

Comment: @RaymondNijland `+--------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                 |
+--------------------------------------------+
| NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+--------------------------------------------+
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go isn't inserting `null`s in your table, it is inserting empty strings. Your code is effectively doing this:

```
seller := Seller{}
seller.SellerName = "testt"
```

to create the `seller` that you're inserting. So all the fields in your `seller` except `SellerName` will have the zero value for their type; the fields causing you trouble are `string`s and the zero value of a `string` is `""` (i.e an empty string) so the SQL ends up looking like:

```
INSERT INTO seller (name, contact, ...)
VALUES ('testt', '', ...)
```

and there isn't a NULL in sight.

You could validate the incoming data in Go so that empty strings are rejected, you could use [`NullString`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString) instead of `string` and let the database deal with `NULL`s (assuming MySQL is properly configured), or do both.

Comment: It's working. You're right, Go wasn't inserting null but empty string. I changed `string` to `sql.NullString` in my model and now everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because when it comes to Mysql: 
emtpy string (e.g '') is NOT a null. 
It treats it like being a string (only empty).